# 'GstV4l2Src' has no property named 'caps'

Tags: c, gstreamer

I'm using GStreamer to get v4l2 data and display it on my panel. For gst-launch-1.0, it is `gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw, format=NV12, width=640, height=480, framerate=30/1 ! waylandsink`, and it works. But when I create the pipeline I get an warning:

```
(demo:914): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 10:18:16.810: g_object_set_is_valid_property: object class 'GstV4l2Src' has no property named 'caps'
Using mplane plugin for capture
```

in my code:

```c
    /* Set caps on source */
    caps = gst_caps_new_simple(
        "video/x-raw", 
        "format", G_TYPE_STRING, "YUV2", 
        "width", G_TYPE_INT, 1920, 
        "height", G_TYPE_INT, 1080, 
        "framerate", GST_TYPE_FRACTION, 30, 1,
        NULL
    );
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(source), "device", "/dev/video0", "caps", caps, NULL);
    gst_caps_unref(caps);
```

I want to know how to set the data format which is captured by v4l2. Should I use [prepare_format_callback()](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/video4linux2/v4l2src.html?gi-language=c#signals) ? But I found very little information about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`v4l2src` does not have a caps property. What you are doing in the first line is actually a convenience shortcut because caps are often being used in a pipeline.

Manually you would construct this pipeline differently:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! capsfilter caps="video/x-raw, format=NV12, width=640, height=480, framerate=30/1" ! waylandsink
```

You will need to adjust your code to add a `capsfilter` element and set the `caps` property on that element instead.